# Перенаправление на страницу с нескольких

Tags: django

Имеется такой код:

```
#urls.py
path('', MainFormView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('index', MainFormView.as_view(), name='home'),
path('home', MainFormView.as_view(), name='home'),
...
#base.html
{% if request.path == '/home' %}
    {{ блок }}
{% endif %}
```

У одной страницы несколько адресов. На этой странице должен выводиться блок, но условие стоит на один путь. Как сделать лаконично на все без перечисления в условии? Или как сделать редиректы с первого и второго путей на третий?

**UDP**: код `view`:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MainFormView(DataMixin, FormView):
    form_class = MainForm
    template_name = 'sitee/index.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['menu_selected'] = 'home'
        c_def = self.get_user_context(title="Главная")
        return dict(list(context.items()) + list(c_def.items()))

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect('home')
```

на эту страницу ведет три пути:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1/index
127.0.0.1/home
```

Как сделать, что бы при попытке перейти на `127.0.0.1` и `127.0.0.1/index` нас переводило на `127.0.0.1/home`? Это нужно для того, что бы в шаблоне было такое условие `if request.path == '/home'` , а не такое `if request.path == '/home' or request.path == '/index' or request.path == '/'`

Либо же можно оставить без редиректа, а использовать в условии нечто такое: `if request.name == 'home'`, т.е. если указано имя страницы, не важно какой у нее путь, условие выполнялось

Comment: обьясните по подробнее вашу проблему.

Comment: вы можете показать ваш views.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#urls.py

```
path('', MainFormView.as_view(), name='main'),
path('index', MainFormView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('home', MainFormView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

#base.html

```
{% if 'home' in request.path %}

    <h1>Home</h1>

{% elif 'index' in request.path %}

<h1>Index</h1>

{% else %}

<h1>Main</h1>

{% endif %}
```

чтобы получить 'name' в urls.py вы можете использовать {{ request.resolver_match.view_name }}.поэтому можно вот так сделать.

```
  {% if 'home' in request.resolver_match.view_name %}

    <h1>Home</h1>

{% elif 'index' in request.resolver_match.view_name %}

<h1>Index</h1>

{% else %}

<h1>Main</h1>

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добавил информацию в вопросе

Comment: исправил условие в вопросе)

Comment: @helldrg этот код работает

Comment: Вопрос в том, как избежать такой структуры `if request.path == '/home' or request.path == '/index' or request.path == '/'`, так как путь `/home` может удалиться или измениться и его придется менять во многих местах

Comment: @helldrg я изменил мой код.

Comment: я сделал так что только 'name' в urls.py проверяет это удобнее.

Comment: @helldrg сейчас нормально ?

Comment: Идеально! Благодарю!!! Спасибо

Comment: @helldrg я рад что помог тебе.Happy Coding)

Comment: ааааа, я понял почему меня не поняли, я не правильно urls переписал, там везде name="home" стоит. Извините пожалуйста =) Спасибо большое!

Comment: ааа, нее, я правильно написал, у Вас `name` разные были =)

Comment: @helldrg да лучше сделать name уникальный для всех проэктах.

Comment: они одинаковые специально, что бы на одну страницу вели =)

Comment: если бы можно было, я бы так написал  `path(['home','index',''], MainFormView.as_view(), name='home')` =)

Comment: @helldrg понял но так нельзя.